# Saving images with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a node app using Sequelize as my ORM over Postgres. But the Sequelize docs are missing any mention of how to do datablob, specifically image, saving. Does anyone know:

1. How to save an image to the database using sequelize, for example from a form. I seems like I need to convert the image to binary data somehow from what I can tell.
2. How to create seeds with images so that I can test before my app goes live.

Here is my migration file for an example model

```
export default {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      firstName: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      photo: { <--------------------------- Image
        type: Sequelize.BLOB,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  },
};
```

As well as a small seed file

```
export default {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /*
      Add altering commands here.
      Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

      Example:
      return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Persons', [{
        name: 'John Doe',
        isBetaMember: false
      }], {});
    */
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [
      {
        firstName: 'Ricky',
        lastName: 'Sparks',
        // photo: <---------- what should I fill in here to seed with a photo file?
        email: 'email@gmail.com',
        createdAt: Sequelize.fn('NOW'),
        updatedAt: Sequelize.fn('NOW'),
      },
    ]);
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /*
      Add reverting commands here.
      Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

      Example:
      return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Persons', null, {});
    */

    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
  },
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try [Sequelize-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-file) , let it handle the file storage,association with models and reading back from blob. Other than that you can use the buffer,stream in the request object of the framework you are using usually the modules expose an buffer or stream or whatever.

the flow usually goes as below.

when submitting

- submit form -> http request object -> read buffer -> store to blob

when responding

- read from blob -> to buffer -> build the http response.

About testing you can either create some files manually along with an json file of what are the correct values width/height/image type/etc and use those to read and submit or mock files somehow.

I would personally try to avoid storing files into database as you see its even in theory difficult and not easy to test etc. Instead you can store the files in the filesystem with an encoded filename, store information in database, test existence etc. way easier than doing all that unless its necessary.

Comment: Yeah I was reading about not storing files in the database. I would imagine that the postgres has built in compression and whatnot that would be preferable to saving it on my server's filesystem or building it myself. This made the most sense for a v0 product, with the idea to eventually move to a CDN etc, but I could very well be wrong.

Comment: you can always stress test your solution and get some performance feedback, compression can be handled in http responses PostgreSQL doesn't magically make 100mb image to 10mb .. compression it's kinda pointless that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for question number 1.

step 1.declaring Image Saving model

file: models/imageModel.js

```js
 import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize) => {
  const imageModel = sequelize.define(
    'images',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      image: { 
        type: DataTypes.BLOB('long'), // <- type for image ( database :postgresql )
        allowNull: true 
      },
    },
    { schema: 'imageSchema' },
  );
  return imageModel;
};
```

step 2: model/index.js sequelize connection

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../db.config.js';
import imagesTable from './imageModel.js';

const db = {};

// create Schema if not Exist
// might crash the Node on first npm start if no Schema Exist, run again
(async () => {
  await sequelize.showAllSchemas({ logging: false }).then(async (data) => {
    if (!data.includes('imageSchema')) await sequelize.createSchema('imageSchema');
  });
})();

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.images = imagesTable(sequelize, DataTypes);

export default db;
```

step 2:
converting image to buffer using jimp(^0.16.1) and file-type(^17.1.2) for reading image meta info,[install jimp using npm and file-type(if required)]

```js
  const imagePath = `path/to/image`;
  const jimpImageToBuffer = await jimp
    .read(imagePath) // read image from path
    .then((ele) => {
      const mimeForImage = ele._originalMime;
      return ele.getBufferAsync(mimeForImage); // convert image to buffer(compatiable to save to database).
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  console.log(jimpImageToBuffer); // <- image in buffer, save this file in database(in image column)
  const imageExtensionAndMIME = await fileTypeFromFile(imagePath); // extract image extension and image type.
  const { ext: imageExtension, mime: imageMimeType } = imageExtensionAndMIME;
```

step 3: In repository.

```js
import db from "../models/index.js"

// save to database using sequelize
export const saveImagesToDatabse = async (imageDetails) => {
  const savedImages = await db.images.create(imageDetails);
  return savedImages;
};
```