# How to Convert buffer into image using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

This is my code that I'm getting image from the S3 bucket but the results are in buffer I need that to be image. Please tell me to do that

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: '################',
    secretAccessKey: '###############################',
    region: '###########'
  })

  const params = {
    Bucket: '#########',
    Key: '########'
  }
  s3.getObject(params, (err, rest) => {
    res.send(rest)
  })
})

app.listen(3000)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 2020-06-29T10:42:17.000Z,
  ContentLength: 338844,
  ETag: '"769af0d798cd0486993711bc63340bd0"',
  ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 02 02 02 
  02 02 02 02 02 02 02 03 03 02 03 03 04 03 03 03 03 04 06 04 04 04 ... 338794 
  more bytes>
}
```

Comment: It all depends on how you want to display this image.  The answer would be different if you wanted to, lets say, display it in html versus save on disk as a file..

Comment: I need to diaplay the image in browser while using the port

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TLDR;**

```js
/**
 * FINAL/WORKING SOLUTION
 */

// ...
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: '-',
    secretAccessKey: '-',
    region: '-',
  });

  const params = {
    Bucket: '-',
    Key: '-',
  };

  s3.getObject(params, (err, rest) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const b64 = Buffer.from(rest.Body).toString('base64');
    // CHANGE THIS IF THE IMAGE YOU ARE WORKING WITH IS .jpg OR WHATEVER
    const mimeType = 'image/png'; // e.g., image/png
    
    res.send(`<img src="data:${mimeType};base64,${b64}" />`);
  });
});
// ...
```

---

***ORIGINAL ANSWER***

You will need to use `node` to 'render' the image.. aka just send the response as an `<img />` tag..

```js
// ...
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: '-',
    secretAccessKey: '-',
    region: '-',
  });

  const params = {
    Bucket: '-',
    Key: '-',
  };

  s3.getObject(params, (err, rest) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const b64 = Buffer.from(rest).toString('base64');
    // NOTE: 
    // Because 'rest' appears to be a buffer, you might not 
    // need to do `Buffer.from(...)`,you may have to do something like:
    /** const b64 = rest.toString('base64'); **/
    const mimeType = 'image/png'; // e.g., image/png
    
    res.send(`<img src="data:${mimeType};base64,${b64}" />`);
  });
});
// ...
```

---

***EDIT 1:***

I believe the issue has something to do with how the data is returned to you from S3.. You may have to do something like `rest.Body` or `rest.body` - I am not sure what the object from S3 looks like.

With that being said, I saved [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vex8.png) locally as `sample.png`, and used the code below to load it - it worked just fine. This is proof the issue has something to do with how S3 is returning that data to you.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Simulate getting data from S3 (aka data as buffer)
  const rest = Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync('./sample.png'));

  console.log('typeof rest = ' + typeof rest + '\r\n\r\n', rest);
  // typeof rest = object
  //
  // <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 34 00 00 00 a4 08 03 00 00 00 2e 4e 22 5a 00 00 00 a2 50 4c 54 45 f7 f7 f7 cd 00 00 d1 00 00 ... 6360 more bytes>


  const b64 = rest.toString('base64');
  const mimeType = 'image/png'; // e.g., image/png

  res.send(`<img src="data:${mimeType};base64,${b64}" />`);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

---

***EDIT 2:***

It looks like you'll need to do this:

```js
// ...
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: '-',
    secretAccessKey: '-',
    region: '-',
  });

  const params = {
    Bucket: '-',
    Key: '-',
  };

  s3.getObject(params, (err, rest) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const b64 = Buffer.from(rest.Body).toString('base64');
    // IF THE ABOVE LINE DOES NOT WORK, TRY THIS:
    // const b64 = rest.Body.toString('base64');

    // CHANGE THIS IF THE IMAGE YOU ARE WORKING WITH IS .jpg OR WHATEVER
    const mimeType = 'image/png'; // e.g., image/png
    
    res.send(`<img src="data:${mimeType};base64,${b64}" />`);
  });
});
// ...
```

Comment: It shoeing some error :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object

Comment: It shows the buffer value which I posted as OUTPUT previously

Comment: I've made some changes it working but not as I expected it only showing the image icon in the browser not the entire image

Comment: @Sethu please see the bottom of my answer - I have added some updates.

Comment: Yeah I'm used your code by placing the image locally it worked fine. But I'm not sure about the S3. I've another code that displays the image from S3 perfectly but I don't need that. If you want to see that code I will show you

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of the output from console.log(rest) ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Matt Oestreich

Comment: @Sethu please see Edit 2 in my answer as I have updated it.

Comment: This is the console that came from S3                                                                                               {
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 2020-06-29T10:42:17.000Z,
  ContentLength: 338844,
  ETag: '"769af0d798cd0486993711bc63340bd0"',
  ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 02 02 02 
  02 02 02 02 02 02 02 03 03 02 03 03 04 03 03 03 03 04 06 04 04 04 ... 338794 
  more bytes>
}

Comment: @Sethu thank you, and no problem - I'm glad to help. Did you see the updates to my answer?

Comment: Yeah Edit 2 works good @ Matt Oestreich. Thanks for your help

Comment: may I know do you have knowledge in AWS Lambda ?

Comment: I understand the logic behind Lambda/Azure Functions/Whatever Google calls their offering.. that is what is important here. It's basically just handling a route. Besides, the issue at hand had nothing to do with Lambda =/

Answer (score 0):

The first, let convert the buffer to string (in this case, we use `base64` string)
Then, return a simple html page to display base64 string image.

Follow the function will convert a buffer to a string

```
  const encode = (data) => {
    let buf = Buffer.from(data);
    let base64 = buf.toString('base64');
    return base64
  }
```

The send the html page to client:

```
    const html = `<html><body><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,${encode(rest.Body)}'/></body></body></html>`
    res.send(html)
```

As you see, `rest.Body` is the buffer content of the image.

Final code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: '################',
    secretAccessKey: '###############################',
    region: '###########'
  })

  const params = {
    Bucket: '#########',
    Key: '########'
  }

  const encode = (data) => {
    let buf = Buffer.from(data);
    let base64 = buf.toString('base64');
    return base64
  }

  s3.getObject(params, (err, rest) => {
    const html = `<html><body><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,${encode(rest.Body)}'/></body></body></html>`
    res.send(html)
  })
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Try using Jimp library to convert image to buffer,which can be saved in database as well.

```js
 const imagePath = `path/to/image`;
  const jimpImageToBuffer = await jimp
    .read(imagePath) // read image from path
    .then((ele) => {
      const mimeForImage = ele._originalMime;
      return ele.getBufferAsync(mimeForImage); // convert image to buffer(compatiable to save to database).
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  console.log(jimpImageToBuffer); // <- image in buffer format
```

check the below link for implementation and full explanation of jimp conversion of image to buffer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72798711/18383251